Node Gives Connection Failed
When I run my node.js code, it gives me following error,
I have connected the MongoDB database with this code. But now it shows as connection failed.
I have installed nodemon and express.jsin this project.
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Connection failed!
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

The index.js as follows,
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = require('./model/product.model.js');

const app = express()

app.use(express.json());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from Node API updated"); //response is coming from node api
});

// app.post('/api/products', (req, res) =>{
//     res.send("Data Recieved");
// });

app.get('/api/products', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const products = await Product.find({});
    }catch (error){
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message});
    }
});

app.post('/api/products', async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        const product = await Product.create(req.body);
        res.status(200).json(product);
    }catch (error){
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message});
    }
});

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin:@backenddb.z8xdl.mongodb.net/Node-API?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=BackendDB")
.then(() =>{
    console.log("Connected to database!");
    app.listen(3000, ()=> {
        console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
    });
})
.catch(() => {
    console.log("Connection failed!");
})


in the catch try taking the error and logging the error message

Print the full error message instead of static text "Connection failed!" which does not provide any information.

I go to the MondoDB site and reconnected the database. Then the error resolved.

Go to the MongoDB site and reconnect the database. Then re-run the code.
